# What makes this binary search move closer to the max range?

Tags: c++, loops, binary-search, do-while

I'm making a small number guessing program (call it my first step to make a real game). It has two main modes that lets the user guess the computer's number (which I got easy enough) and where the user picks the number and the computer has to get it. Both modes work on the user typing "high" or "low" or "exact" in some form to get closer to the answer.

But I'm having trouble with using binary search to get the computer to find the number the user picks. It all runs and I'm able to get to the mode, but whenever I press enter it simply goes to the max range (range is from 1-100). I fear there's some minor logic malfunction in my binary search but from what I can see.

While I was writing this, I found a new bug. If I type guess and guess the computer's number and type guess again it simply loops until I press pick or quit. I still haven't looked into it yet. But any input would be appreciated.

My goal for myself is to at least get into more complex text based game logic or actually start on physical graphics.

Program itself....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
   int i, randomNumber, guess
        , computerGuess, middle;

   int last = 100;
   int first =1;

   string choice, answer;

   srand(time(NULL));
   randomNumber= (rand()% last + first);


   //Loop entire program until QUIT is specified.
   do{

      i = 0;

      cout << "\n\nGood day, I would like to play";
      cout << " a number guessing game" << endl;
      cout << "Type QUIT to quit the program \n" << endl;

      cout << "Who would you like to be?" << endl;
      cout << "Guesser or picker?" << endl;
      getline(cin,choice);

      //Changes the string choice to uppercase
      while (i<choice.size()){
         choice[i] = toupper(choice[i]);
         i++;
      }

      //initiates guess mode
      if (choice.find("GUESS") != string::npos){
         cout << "You picked guess." << endl;
      while (guess != randomNumber){
         cout << "Please guess the computer's number." << endl;
         cin >> guess;

            //User guesses and computer responds
            if (guess == randomNumber){
               cout << "\nYou guess right!\n" << endl;
            } else if (guess > randomNumber){
               cout << "\nToo high!\n" << endl;
            } else if (guess < randomNumber){
               cout << "\nToo low!\n" << endl;
            } else {
               cout << "ERROR" << endl;
            }
          }
      }

      //Initiates pick mode
      if (choice.find("PICK") != string::npos){
            cout << "\nYou want to pick the number." << endl;
            cout << "Have the number in your head?"<< endl;
            cout << "Alright, I'll guess.\n\n" << endl;


            //start binary search
            do{
               middle= (last+first)/2;

               cout << "Is " << middle << " the number?" << endl;
               getline (cin,answer);
               //changes answer to uppercase
               while (i<answer.size()){
               answer[i] = toupper(answer[i]);
               i++;
               }
               //add (middle+1) to first if LOW
               if (answer.find("LOW")){
                  first = middle +1;
               }else if (answer.find("HIGH")){
                  //add (middle-1) to last if HIGH
                  last = middle -1;
               }

            }while (answer.find("EXACT") == string::npos);
            cout << "So the number is " << middle << endl;

      }
   }while (choice.find("QUIT") == string::npos);
   return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure if this fixes all the issues but I did see a couple of bugs:

In the section of your code in the do{.. } loop below the comment: //start binary search

First bug:  When converting to uppercase you have:

```
while (i<answer.size()){
    answer[i] = toupper(answer[i]);
    i++;
}
```

but you have i defined earlier in the code so when you reach this part of your program, i is nonzero or might be bigger than answer.size(), then your string doesn't get converted properly.

So what you want is something like this with a new index, say k:

```
int k = 0;
while (k<answer.size()){
    answer[k] = toupper(answer[k]);
    k++;
}
```

Second bug:  You should use string.find() like this in your code:

```
if (answer.find("LOW")!= std::string::npos){
    first = middle + 1;
} else if (answer.find("HIGH")!= std::string::npos){
    last = middle - 1;
}
```

rather than the way you have it listed, otherwise, the first and last values don't get updated properly.

After these changes, the computer search worked fine for me.

If you have a debugger, step through your code at these locations and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Hey thanks for the input. Even better thanks for explaining why things happen the way they did. It'll help me not to make the same mistake again.